# Write the closed form of the corresponding series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following sequence, written in closed form

$$ a_n^2-3a_n $$

$(a) \ $ Write the closed form of the corresponding series , where the lower limit is $ \ 6 \ $ and the upper limit is $ \ 9 \ $.

$ (b) \ $ Write that entire  series in open form.

$ (c) \ $ Write the second term of the series .

**Answer:**

$ (a) \ $

I don't know how to start the answer.

I think , let $ a_{n+1}=a_n^2-3a_n \ $

Since lower limit is $ 6 \ $ and upper limit is $ \ 9 \ $ , we should have

$$ 6=a_0 \leq a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_{n+1}=9 \ $$

Now in order to find the closed form of the corresponding series we have to evaluate the series $ \ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n^2-3a_n) \ $

**But I am unable to find that.**

**Help me out**

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: $a_n^2-3a_n$ is not a sequence, and isn't the "upper limit" of any *series* just $+\infty$?

Comment: That is all given in the question and it is a sequence $ a_n^2-3a_n \ $

Comment: No, a sequence is typically a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and that is not a sequence. $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ where $a_0=\text{something}$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-3a_n$ **is** a sequence, yours is just an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take $(a)$ to mean $\displaystyle \sum_{n=6}^9 (a_n^2 -3a_n) = (a_6^2 -3a_6) + (a_7^2-3a_7) + (a_8^2-3a_8) + (a_9^2-3a_9).$

Comment: I would take the LHS of your answer to be the answer to (a) and the RHS to be the answer to (b)

Comment: @Acccumulation : I'd say they're both closed forms. It seems stupid to consider something not a closed form merely because it uses Sigma notation. If it had said $\sum_{n=6}^N (a_n^2-3a_n)$ and was concerned with the dependence of the value upon (capital) $N,$ then you could say it's not a closed form.